# Pivot sql output - Google sql Interview question

Tags: sql

I have asked to query a table to return the names of the student that starts with A along with their count. Let us table has "Alan" and "Adam" entry. The output should be 2, Alan, Adam.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-server`, ctc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left()` with window function :

```
select name, count(*) over ()
from table t
where left(fname, 1) = 'a';
```

Edit : Use `string_agg()` to concat strings into single row :

```
select count(*), string_agg(fname, ', ')
from table t
where left(fname, 1) = 'a';
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not give expected output, output should be 2,Adam,Alan. One single row

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left()`, and `string_agg()`.

**Option 1:** which you have asked for.

```
select
    count(firstChar) as totalCount,
    string_agg(fname, ', ') as allNames
from
(
    select 
        fname,
        left(fname, 1) as firstChar
    from myName
) res
group by
   firstChar
```

Output: [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j5xN8wc2wB4wi6vnUQwzJr/0)

```
*----------------------*
|totalcount | allnames |
*----------------------*
|   2       |Adam, Alan|
*----------------------*
```

**Option 2:**

```
select 
    left(fname, 1) as firstChar, 
    count(left(fname, 1)) as total
from myName
group by
    left(fname, 1)
```

Output: [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bAsHvYkQyEmu6ZFf4zPkCJ/0)

```
*-------------------*
|firstChar  | count |
*-------------------*
|   A       |    2  |
*-------------------*
```

Comment: Thanks. You are gem. I was looking for Option 1. Option 2 is easy to do. I was not aware of string_agg function.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, I would use `array_agg()`:

```
select count(*), array_agg(name)
from t
where name like 'A%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find Answer as per your output:
I have created a table below:

```
Create table dbo.test_table (FNAME varchar(50));

insert into dbo.test_table(FNAME) values
('Alan'),
('Adam')
```

Query for the output:

```
with CTE AS (
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as total_Count,
    string_agg(fname, ', ') as First_Names
FROM dbo.test_table
WHERE LEFT(FNAME,1)='A'
  )
  SELECT CONCAT(total_Count,',', First_Names) As output FROM CTE
```

[image]

`SQL Fiddle` Link for output:
[SQLFiddle](https://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7fe7/1/0)